# Elasticsearch / Logstash

Tags: rest, api, elasticsearch, logstash

new in the ELK stack maybe my question is stupid.  Sorry if it's the case :-)

I want to get datas from several APIs and transform it to push it in elasticsearch. Is there a way to do it directly with logstash?
I tried Http-poller but that's not really what I want since I cannot updated the data based on time column and I cannot browse api data.

Have I to code it manually ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Http input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http.html) in logstash.

check this for an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37585290/5430055